# how do I check if a 2 dimensional python list contains only number 1

Tags: python

Assume I have a two dimensional list and not using numpy,not using two for loop in this case.

```py
a = [[0,0,0],[1,0,0]]
b = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

is there any function to determine that a list contain only 1 or 0.

any() and all() won't work on the 2D list I think.

```py
a = [[0,0,0][1,0,0]]
b = [[0,0,0][0,0,0]]

I want

if allListItemsAreZero(b):
    print(‘this works’)
```

Comment: Does `all(col == 0 for row in a for col in row)` count as two for loops?

Comment: You can't avoid the `for` loops- maybe you can hide them (using `itertools` perhaps), but under the hood you have to check each element until you find one that's different. **Edit**: unless you do something weird like convert to string...

Comment: @jonClements I have tried this, this won't work.

Comment: @jinweiZhang could you elaborate on why?

Comment: Also your `list`s are not valid python lists. This seems like a [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean all elements should be either 0's or 1's? Or there should only be one 0 or one 1 in all the sublists? Not very clear @jinweiZhang

Answer (score 0):

There are two things in your question.

1. your lists have to be corrected

   a = [[0,0,0][1,0,0]] ==> a = [[0,0,0],[1,0,0]]

and then below kind of code should help you.

```
a = [[0,0,0],[1,0,0]]
for x in a:
  print(x.count(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use `itertools` from the standard library, this is a way to do it:

```
from itertools import chain

def allListItemsAreZero(input_list):
    for n in chain.from_iterable(input_list):
        if n != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Corrected, although it would work if OP's use case is 0 or 1 only.

Comment: This uses two for loops, but at least the short circuiting will improve performance. Still, it's unclear what OP's true requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

To check all `0s` we can use `any` to check if we encounter a 1 in the sublist (Thanks @JonClements for the idea)

```
def check_all_zeros(a):
    return not any(c != 0 for r in a for c in r)

print(check_all_zeros([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]))
print(check_all_zeros([[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]))
```

The output will be

```
True
False
```

A similar idea for checking all `1s`, we check if we encounter a 0 in the sublist

```
def check_all_ones(a):
    return not any(c != 1 for r in a for c in r)

print(check_all_ones([[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]))
print(check_all_ones([[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]))
```

The output will be

```
True
False
```

Comment: Probably a check with `[0] * len(a)` would be better.

Comment: This still uses two for loops (which is basically unavoidable), but performance will be worst possible since you have to iterate over every element.

Comment: Yes iterating over all elements is needed to check if `all` elements are 0 or 1, unfortunately!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh that's not true- you can short circuit like jfaccioni's answer or JonClement's comment. Using `sum` is not a good solution here.

Comment: I assume you mean exiting on seeing the first 1 or 0, @pault ? I have updated my answer accordingly! Please check!

Comment: Now you essentially copied Jon's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55981904/how-do-i-check-if-a-2-dimensional-python-list-contains-only-number-1#comment98613236_55981904) without attribution and didn't even bother to change the variable names.

Comment: Updated to refer Jon's comment! Maybe I am not clear what is `short circuit` @pault Could you explain?